What is the "original spelling" of a preprocessing token?
C++23/cpp.stringize states:

the original spelling of each preprocessing token in the stringizing argument is retained in the character string literal

What does the phrase "original spelling" refers to exactly?
The existing implementations all seem to consistently use the spelling after line splicing, but before UCN replacement. Consider the following snippet:
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR2(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR2(x)

int main()
{
    printf(STR(STR(naïve)));
    printf(STR(STR(na\u{ef}ve)));
    printf(STR(STR(na\u{ef}v\
e)));
}

All implementations end up with the following output:
"naïve""na\u{ef}ve""na\u{ef}ve"

Are they correct?

I guess that the phrase "original spelling" in the context of the C++ preprocessor refers to the exact sequence of preprocessing tokens as they appear before any transformations like line splicing or UCN replacement are applied.
and yes, the implementations you observed are correct. They use the spelling after line splicing but before UCN replacement, resulting in the output: naïve""na\u{ef}ve""na\u{ef}ve

Line splicing happens in phase 2 while pp-tokens are formed in phase 3. It makes no sense to talk about "pp-token spelling before line splicing". There are no pp-tokens at that point.

@HamzaAlAjlouni I'm confused. You said "original spelling [...] refers to [...] tokens as they appear before any transformations like line splicing", but then you say "the implementations [...] are correct. They use the spelling after line splicing [...]". Which one is it?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I agree with your assessment, I would go even further, because UCN replacement happens "as characters from the source file are consumed to form the next preprocessing token", i.e. before the pp-token is formed and as such I would think the correct output is "naïve""naïve""naïve".

I think the standard is too vague in this area.

@avakar Original spelling refers to the exact textual form of the preprocessing tokens as they appear in the source code before any further preprocessing or translation. this is the first point, the second point is that in practice, line splicing happens early in the preprocessing stage before stringizing (#) is applied, because the backslash is a defined behavior in the C and C++ preprocessing stages.so if you are asking about  Original spelling from the documentation, it refers to text as it, and if you are asking about implementation, yes it is correct because line splicing will happen.

The phases of translation may be helpful, or at least slightly relevant.

@HamzaAlAjlouni - "Original spelling refers to the exact textual form of the preprocessing tokens as they appear in the source code before any further preprocessing or translation" It doesn't necessarily. The standard refers to spelling (rather sloppily) in exactly two places: the [cpp] and [lex]. One must be careful not to invent normative definitions from colloquial text used in the standard. If "spelling" is to have any of the meaning you claim it has with regard to translation phases, the standard must define it.

@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica I am not totally sure about my information so don't take my words as a reference, but that is what I know, maybe it is wrong. but I guess my answer is not wrong.

@HamzaAlAjlouni - I'm certain your common sense use of English is correct here. It's just that the standard as a formal document seems to need updating, and I wanted to emphasize that. I did it poorly (but in my defense the 5min grace period for editing comments ran out :) )

This pertains to tokens with multiple spellings, i.e. digraphs (and in previous standards, trigraphs).
[lex.digraph]

2 In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its spelling10.
The set of alternative tokens is defined in Table 3.

And note 10 even mentions the section you quote:

10) Thus the “stringized” values ([cpp.stringize]) of [ and <: will be different, maintaining the source spelling, but the tokens can otherwise be freely interchanged.

The rule you quote basically means that STR2(and) won't pop out as "&&" or vice versa. It's spelled explicitly because IIRC alternative tokens like and could have been implemented as macros, and those would not have preserved the source spelling if implemented naively.
As for UCNs... not only does this "original spelling" verbiage predates them (it exists as far back as C++03 documents, probably in C++98 too if I had access to them), but I don't think the folks working on the recent UCN proposals knew there's this confusing text that needs addressing. I don't believe one can deduce much about UCNs from this verbiage at this point.

Ah, thanks, so that was probably the motivation behind the word "original" in the phrase and it probably means "the spelling at the point the pp-token was formed", which means the form after line-splicing. You don't address whether the original spelling is the one before or after UCN replacement though. The recent addition of UCN replacement changes the behavior of stringization IMO.

@avakar - I don't address it because it's a red herring as far as "alternative spelling" goes. That term as far as I could find only applies to the tokens in [lex.digraph]. That table is complete, exhaustive, and doesn't permit ucn's in lieu of inidividual characters (i.e. <: is okay as a stand in for [, but <\u{003a}for example isn't).

@avakar - I'm also not saying it's not an interesting question in itself, just that it's disjoint from the use of "original spelling" here, so your post actually contains two separate questions through no fault of your own. If the question in the title is not your main focus, then please edit your post to reflect that and I can delete this answer.
